# I dont run mi script junit by .bat

Tags: batch-file, junit

I read other questions like a: "How to run Junit testcases from command line?" and "how to run junit test command line from java [duplicate]"
I still can not run my script from a file .bat:

> java -cp C:\Users\psanchez\Documents\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore C:\Users\psanchez\EclipseWorks\BuscarJava\bin\Serarch BJava.class

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to run it?  It's hard to say what's wrong based on what you've given us.